# using hidden field to add data into database

Tags: php, database, hidden-field

I'm adding data by using a hidden field. Initially it works and shows all the information I needed on my database. However, when I worked on it again, it only captures the same name as previous ones that was already captured before.

For example there is an image of an apple and when I add, it should show the name as apple. Then when I click on the image of a pear, clearly it should shows 'pear' as the name in my database. But instead of 'pear', it shows as apple. Does anyone knows why?

```
<form action="addOrder.php" method="post">
<td class="timgG"><h4><img src="apple.jpg" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" title="Apple"/> Apple <br>
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="add">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Apple"> 
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="0.50">
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</h4></td>

<td class="timgG"><h4><img src="pear.jpg" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" title="Pear"/> Pear <br>
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="add">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Pear"> 
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="0.50">
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</h4></td>
</form>


<?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
                //$order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                //$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
                $price = $_POST['price'];

                $query = "INSERT INTO order_details (name,price) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $price . "')";
                $status = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

                if ($status) {
                    $msg = "Item has been added.<br />";
                    $msg .= "<a href='product.php'>Back</a></p>";
                }
            } else {
                $msg = "There was an error processing the form.Please try again <a href=girls.php>Back";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Its because your `html` inputs have the same name: "`name`".

Comment: Warning: SQL injection possible! Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or, better, use parameterized queries.

Comment: Because the "apple" is the first element of the array. Pear is second.

Comment: you are not escaping data coming from the client. what happens if $_POST['name'] == `'; DELETE ALL FROM ALL YOUR DATABASE ARE BELONG TO US`

Comment: I think solution to your problem will be to use different forms for individual items as suggested by some  .. because even if toy change name to name[] even then you dont have any way to recognize which submit is clicked unless until you use some javascript code

Comment: thanks everyone who had commented and offer suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use individual `<form>` for each item. The current setup (as you will notice if you set the other parameters differently) always uses the first definition of the hidden inputs inside your form.

Try using

```
<form action="addOrder.php" method="post">
<td class="timgG"><h4><img src="apple.jpg" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" title="Apple"/> Apple <br>
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="add">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Apple"> 
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="0.50">
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</h4></td>
</form>

<form action="addOrder.php" method="post">
<td class="timgG"><h4><img src="pear.jpg" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" title="Pear"/> Pear <br>
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="add">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Pear"> 
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="0.50">
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</h4></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `HTML` inputs have the same `name`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Apple"> 

<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Pear">
```

And since `Apple` is first, that's the first one that gets processed by the `PHP`.

A fix would be to either use two different forms with unique submit button names, or to have unique name's for your hidden inputs.

Comment: if my code were to be be 

<input type="hidden" name="apple" value="apple"> 
<input type="hidden" name="pear" value="Pear"> 

it does not capture anything on my database except the price of the items.. @chriz

Comment: if you name it `name="apple"` then do `if(isset($_POST['apple'])){$apple=$_POST['apple'];}` then you can insert `$apple` into the database. you can do this with `pear` aswell

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `name` attribute for the different products in the same form, so you will be overwriting your form fields.

You can use arrays to have multiple items with the same name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="Apple">
// etc.
```

And then in php, `$_POST['name']` will be an array as well.

And you really should switch to prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

use two different forms

```
<form action="addOrder.php" method="post">
<td class="timgG"><h4><img src="apple.jpg" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" title="Apple"/> Apple <br>
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="add">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Apple"> 
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="0.50">
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</h4></td>
</form>
<form action="addOrder.php" method="post">
<td class="timgG"><h4><img src="pear.jpg" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" title="Pear"/> Pear <br>
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="add">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Pear"> 
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="0.50">
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</h4></td>
</form>
```

also as a few people mentioned use mysqli_real_escape_string() when inserting something in your database